# R session crash, when gbm() is applied over factor response variable? please advise

Tags: r, random-forest, gbm, ensemble-learning

Below is the excerpt from code, which I am trying for german credit dataset.

I am trying to make a generic function for ensemble techniques for my shinydashboard.

The problem is with gbm. The R session will crash if the response variable is not converted to a factor.

If the response variable is converted to a factor then RandomForest will not produce the OOB error rate and confusion matrix in its output component.

Please advise.

The response variable is "default". Before applying the model, the
response variable is treated as,

```
    ## load the dataset
    data_x = read.csv("credit.csv")

   ## Preprocessing the dataset

   data_x$default <- ifelse(data_x$default == "yes", 1, 0)



  ##Loading packages

  pacman::p_load(shiny,shinydashboard,gbm, 
  randomForest,ggplot2,ipred,caret,ROCR,dplyr,ModelMetrics)

 user defined function
 model = function(algo =gbm ,distribution = 'bernoulli', 
         type = 'response', set ='AUC',n.trees =10000){

 ## Fit the model

  model<- algo(formula = default ~ ., 
           distribution = distribution,
           data = train,
           n.trees = n.trees,
           cv.fold= 3)

    ## Generate the prediction on the test set

    pred<- predict(object = model,
             newdata = test,
             n.trees = n.trees,
             type = type)

   ## Generate the test set AUCs using the pred

   AUC<- auc(actual = test$default, predicted = pred)


    if (set == 'AUC'){
     return(AUC)
     }

    if (set == 'predictions'){
     return(pred)
     }
    if (set == 'model'){
    return(model)

    }
    else
   return(NULL)

     }

    now call different model
    List of different models
    get_model<- function(algo,type = 'response', ntrees = 10000){
    z= model(algo = algo, type= type, set = 'model')

     }

   Bag_model<- get_model(algo = bagging, type='prob')
   RF_model<- get_model(algo = randomForest)
   GBM_model<- get_model(algo = gbm)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Also, you may need `get(algo)(formula = ..` and pass algo as a string i.e. `get_model(algo = "randomForest")`

Comment: If i pass algo as a string then function wont run. There is no error, R simply states that fatal error encountered. Restarting the session.

Comment: You didn't provide an example.  I tried with `mtcars`, but the dataset is too small for it to work.

Comment: Just a moment I will be sharing the dataset and the full code over github link

Comment: But thanks a lot for your patience and advise. Much Appreciated!!

Comment: Here is the data,

Comment: https://github.com/richie312/Data_Camp_Tutorials_R/blob/master/ML_Tree_App/credit.csv

Comment: This is the link for full code,

Comment: https://github.com/richie312/Data_Camp_Tutorials_R/blob/master/ML_Tree_App/Tree_UI.R